# Merging DataFrame based on conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different DataFrames, one with some values of revenue in zero because I don't have the data and a second one with the data I am missing in the other dataframe.

[image]

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([[2020-01,2020-01,2020-02,2020-02,2020-03,2020-03],['PC','Mobile','PC','Mobile','PC','Mobile'],[1,1.2,1.4,1.8],[1.2,1.4,1.6,2],[0.6,1.4,1.6,0],[0.5,1,1.5,0],[0.8,1.3,0,0],[0.6,1.2,0,0]],
    columns=['Date', 'Platform', "Day 1","Day 7","Day 14","Day 30"])
```

[image]

```
df2=pd.DataFrame([[2020-02,2020-02],['PC','Mobile'],[0.6,1.4,1.6,2],[0.5,1.3,1.6,2.2]], columns=['Date', "Day 1","Day 7","Day 14","Day 30"])
```

What I want to do is to automatically remove the cells that are empty if they are matching the same date, remove it from the first dataframe and concat the whole second dataframe so it is complete.

Is there any way to do this? I have tried to remove the lines with zeros, but as I have more rows with zeros, it is removing cells I want to maintain.

This would be the final output:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For replace `0` by values from `df2` by `date` columns use :

```
df = (df1.set_index('date')
         .replace(0, np.nan)
         .combine_first(df2.set_index('date'))
         .fillna(0)
         .reset_index())
print (df)
      date  Day 1  Day 7  Day 14  Day 30
0  2020-01    1.0    1.2     1.4     1.8
1  2020-02    0.6    1.4     1.6     2.0
2  2020-03    0.8    1.3     1.7     2.2
3  2020-04    0.7    0.0     0.0     0.0
```

If possible aggregate `mean` without `0` values by `df1` use:

```
df = (pd.concat([df1.replace(0, np.nan), df2])
        .groupby('date', as_index=False).mean()
        .fillna(0)) 
print (df)

      date  Day 1  Day 7  Day 14  Day 30
0  2020-01    1.0    1.2     1.4     1.8
1  2020-02    0.6    1.4     1.6     2.0
2  2020-03    0.8    1.3     1.7     2.2
3  2020-04    0.7    0.0     0.0     0.0
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It triplicates each row and mixes the results for each day, unfortunately. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MatmataHi - so it means there are duplicated dates? In another words - sample data working perfectly, real data not, what is difference?

Comment: I have another column with the 'platform' (PC and mobile) that I need to put in the index. Then, it duplicates the values... That's the only difference. I didn't mention is to short the problem.

Comment: @MatmataHi - Is possibe change data sample for this problem?

Comment: @MatmataHi - so if use `.set_index(['platform', 'date'])` instead `.set_index('date')` it create wrong ouput?

Comment: I have changed the sample data, @jezrael. Yes. if I use both of them in the set_index, it create a wrong output duplicating each row per date and platform. And only on the rows I want to modify.

Comment: @MatmataHi - do you try data from question use for my solution? Because I try use your data and still failed. `df1=pd.DataFrame([[2020-01,2020-01,2020-02,2020-02,2020-03,2020-03],['PC','Mobile','PC','Mobile','PC','Mobile'],[1,1.2,1.4,1.8],[1.2,1.4,1.6,2],[0.6,1.4,1.6,0],[0.5,1,1.5,0],[0.8,1.3,0,0],[0.6,1.2,0,0]],
    columns=['Date', 'Platform', "Day 1","Day 7","Day 14","Day 30"])` failed for me.